# How to tell visual studio to rebuild every time I make a change?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

How to tell visual studio to rebuild every time I make a change when I hit the play or run exectuable button?

I am trying a c++ application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `Tool->Options->Projects and solutions->Build and run->On Run`, when projects are out of date" should be "Prompt to build" or "Always build"

Comment: ok, let's check Tool->Options->"Projects and solutions"->"Build and run"->"On Run, when projects are out of date" should be "Prompt to build" or "Always build"

Answer (score 4):

[image: Tool -- Option -- Projects and Solutions]

I think your looking for this under **Tool -- Option -- Projects and Solutions**

I don't know that you can configure it to ReBuild (as compared to Build).

One option would be to record a macro and then attaching a hotkey to it.

I recorded this in VS2008

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module RecordingModule


    Sub RebuildThenRun()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand ("Build.RebuildSolution")
    DTE.Debugger.Go(False)
    End Sub
End Module
```